# Parameter value from links-own

Tags: netlogo

I need help!

So I want to specify a parameter in the agents own as an average of the values of a parameter in links-own.

```
frienships-own [strength]
household-own [ influence-factor]

to create-influence
   if friendship = TRUE
   [
     ask household
     [
       if count my-links > 1
       [
         set influence-factor (sum [strength] of link-neighbors) / (count my-links)
       ]
     ]
  ]
end
```

I tried this but doesn't do anything. The idea is to specify the variable "influence-factor" as an average of the variable "strength" which is a variable owned by the households with unidirectional links to other households.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Amanda, it would be very helpful if you posted a [mre]: a **small** (minimal) version of your code that we can simply copy&paste on our side to reproduce the same problem that you are describing. Also, please format your code as code by using backticks (this: ` ), which makes it far easier to read. It is possible to guess a couple of things to fix in what you posted, but it is harder to properly help you without these two aspects I suggested above.

Comment: What is the variable “friendship”? Isn’t defined anywhere here. What is my-links? You can use the `mean` function to get an average.