# I need to count each visit made by a household to a shop

Tags: netlogo

I have two different breeds in my model, households and shops.
I want the shops to count each visit received from households. Households move physically to the shops' location on each tick.

So far I have:

```
    to count-v 
    ask unhealthy-shops [set count-visit-nh count-visit-nh + count households-on self]   
    ask healthy-shops [set count-visit-h count-visit-h + count households-on self]
    end
```

However, this counts the households on the same patch, giving me a bigger number than the actual households in one tick. I only want to count the households in the same location as the shop.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say: *However, this counts the households on the same patch* and also *I only want to count the households in the same location as the shop*. Based on what we know I don't understand the difference between these two things. Do you mean that you want to add the number of households that visited **now**, instead of also including those that may be on that patch from a previous visit? Please note that, also to have these things clear, it is important that you provide a [mre] of your problem (as also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70026906/parameter-value-from-links-own))

Comment: Hi Matteo, sorry I still haven't learned to provide a reproducible example. I have households and shops as turtles. I have a total of 100 households. Every tick a household visits a shop. When I use the code provided above to count the number of visits by households, the result is more than 100 as each shop counts all the households that are on that patch which might have 2 different shops. I want to count only the households that are at the same location as the shop. Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: No need to be sorry, just aim for providing a piece of code (the shortest possible) that anyone can simply copy&paste on their side to reproduce exactly the type of problem you are experiencing (without the need to add anything or make any changes). In this case, anyway, I think it would be ideal to see the code that is run by households and that makes them visit a shop - because I think it is there that I would go to fix the problem. But let me understand, do you mean that there are/can be multiple shops on the same patch? I posted an answer, in case let's bring the discussion there

Comment: is it possible to simply make sure that 2 shops are never on the same patch? seems like you're adding a lot of overhead for a problem that seemingly doesn't have to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the exchange in the comments: here a generalised idea that, in case it fits your code, you will need to adapt to whatever procedures and variables you have beyond `count-v`.

The only key point is to **make sure that the act of counting does not happen based on patches but is instead performed by households when they visit a shop**.

For instance, see the reproducible example below:

```
breed [shops shop]
breed [households household]

shops-own [
  healthy?
  visits-count
]

to setup
  clear-all

  ; Here we make sure that both shops are on the same patch,
  ; and that one is healthy while the other is unhealthy.
  ask patch 0 0 [
    sprout-shops 2 [
      ifelse (any? shops with [healthy? = TRUE])
        [set healthy? FALSE]
        [set healthy? TRUE]

      set shape "house"
      set size 2
      set color blue
    ]
  ]
  
  create-households 20 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color gray
    set shape "person"
  ]
end


to go
  ask households [
    ifelse (random 2 < 1)
      [visit-a-shop]
      [move-to one-of patches with [not any? shops-here]]
  ]
end


to visit-a-shop
  let target one-of shops
  move-to target
  ask target [
    set visits-count (visits-count + 1)
  ]
end
```

Of course the key part here is in `visit-a-shop`. This way, only the households who visit a shop, and only upon visiting it, will update its counter.

---

I see from your code that you have two different counter variables for two different types of shops (i.e. `count-visit-h` and `count-visit-nh`). Let me ask: is that really needed? Because if shops have the counter variable named the same both for healthy and unhealthy shops, then it is easy to just do `set visits-count (visits-count + 1)`, as I did in the example. Otherwise, with two variables named differently, you would have to introduce a condition to check what type of shop the household is visiting, and use the correct variable based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh,  so you move households to the exact same location as a shop,  measured in sub-patch accuracy.  So the shop might be in patch 3 4 but at xcor = 3.1 and ycor = 4.2?

Then you need to compare x and y coordinates, and compare them with "myself" not "self",

as in:

```
ask turtle 0 [ print count turtles with [ xcor = [xcor] of myself and ycor = [ycor] of myself ]]
```

Wade